# Is there a way to get rid of css with react?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

Helo, I am new to reactJS. I am currently doing a full stack job on a forum-like website.

I was naively wondering if there is no way to just ignore the CSS step...
For example, I want to declare a standard component, let's say a `button` or a `form`. 
 I just want to simply set the `className` so the it matches with the CSS stuff.

I did some search, and found nothing very convenient.

And of course, this "library" has to be open-source.

Don't know if I am clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to style your components without having separate css files?

Comment: The simplest way to do this is by using the style property instead of className. But it quickly becomes unmaintainable

Comment: Another solution is to use tailwind css or chakra ui

Comment: @ShamPooSham I want to be able to style my components by using a library. I don't want to do the CSS if possible (or just import a library which contains some "default" CSS stuff).

Comment: @ShamPooSham, I've heard about tailwind css, but isn't it paying ?

Comment: There is tailwind css and tailwind ui. The former is free and the latter costs. But tailwind css might not be the best for you if you're not comfortable with css to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi from the looks of it and the comments, it looks like you want a pre-built UI library. Basically, for React these are called UI Libraries, we have React-Bootstrap, Material UI and Kendo UI as UI libraries. They have pre-made React components with all the styling already implemented and any customization can be done separately.

You can have a look at React-Bootstrap for an easy solution to your problem.